# Is there a way in SQL Server to uniquely identify a database?

Tags: sql-server

Is there any way to uniquely identify a database?

If we were to copy a database to another machine, this instance is assumed to be different. I checked on master tables, but could not identify any information that can identify this.

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing - none of these answers work for me either, since the goal is for the ID not to be valid if the database is moved to a different computer.

Comment: It's an old post but I was looking for the same thing and I found the checksum (generated on install) that is unique for any SQL Server and works even if it's an express edition. It's on HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Setup. HOWEVER I'm not sure if changing this checksum would harm SQL Server...

Answer (score 4):

`service_broker_guid` in [`sys.databases`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178534.aspx) comes pretty close to what you ask. It is a uniqueidentfier generated when the database is created and is preserved as the database is moved around (detach and attach, backup and restored, server rename etc). It can be explicitly changed with `ALTER DATABASE ... SET NEW_BROKER;`.

Comment: Will need exactly opposite of that i think. If a database is copied to a new server, then this has to be marked unique. If i combine server name and the id, this might make it unique.

Answer (score 3):

You could make a table in it with a unique name, and simply do a query on that.  It's a bit of a hack, sure, but it'd work...

Comment: If i copy a database, i am not sure if we can identify if the database has changed. Not sure if i am missing something, can you elaborate a bit more please?

Comment: that changes the wording inference.  Do you mean for a way to recognise a db on another machine, or a way to make the db change when it is copied to another machine, or a way to confirm the db has somehow changed on the other machine?

Answer (score 3):

You could put the information in an extended property associated with the database itself:

```
USE AdventureWorks2008R2;
GO
EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty 
@name = N'MS_DescriptionExample', 
@value = N'AdventureWorks2008R2 Sample OLTP Database';
GO
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190243.aspx

In your case, I would use something like this:

```
EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty 
@name = N'UniqueID', 
@value = N'10156435463';

select objname, [name], [value] 
from fn_listextendedproperty (null, null, null, null, null, null, null)
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a scalar function that returns an ID/Version number:

```
create function fnGetThisDBID() returns varchar(32) as begin
    return ('v1.1,origin=server1')
end 

select 'version is: ' + dbo.fnGetThisDBID()
```