# How to identify a database when it's being moved to another server/instance

Tags: sql, sql-server, guid, identification

I'm writing a tool which is used to perform several database operations.
But the tool should only be used with one specific database.

Now I'm looking for a way, to securely identify the database, the tool is connected to.

First I thought about just checking a string like `SERVERNAME\INSTANCE#Database`.
Also I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10916991/obtaining-a-unique-database-identifier-for-sql-server-2005-and-later) question where the solution is to use a GUID, but this GUID changes if the DB is restored on another server.

The DB should be recognized even when it is being moved to another server or instance, or if the database name changes.

Is there a reliable way to achieve this?

Comment: how about creating a table and reading that info,assuming no one changes the table contents

Comment: Probably a duplicate of or at least related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2957220/is-there-a-way-in-sql-server-to-uniquely-identify-a-database

Comment: @TheGameiswar I also thought about this before. But it should be secure from manipulation.

Comment: does table names change or new tables gets added over time

Comment: @Mithrandir The mentioned solutions are really near to what i'm looking for but all methods are prone to manipulation.

Comment: @TheGameiswar New tables could be added over time.

Comment: @MatSnow Well, depending on how many users have the right set of permissions, any method will be prone to manipulation.

Comment: Only way I see to do this "manipulation free" is by you setting up/verifying the connections to potential databases manually. Especially if the DB can be moved and renamed across servers.

Comment: What exactly must be specific in a database?

Comment: @Serg The database itself. I absolutely understand that a restored DB on a new instance get's a new GUID. Because for the new instance it is like a new DB. I'm just wondering if there is something like a "second GUID" to determine if it originally was the same DB as on the old instance.

Comment: @MatSnow,since server changes wont be so often, you might want to update tool at that point of time

Comment: @TheGameiswar Of Course, this is the solution i will use now. But there's more the problem that the tool is not planned to be updated in future. :-)

Comment: You could use the logical name of the database, this doesn't change afaik if the physical name changes with a restore. `select Name from sys.database_files`

Comment: this is an interesting problem,but all solutions are prone to manipulations like Mithrandir suggested

Comment: @Silvermind Filenames don't change automatically if you rename or restore a DB, but  they can be changed manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to achieve this with an [extended property](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190243(v=sql.105).aspx).

To create:

```
exec sp_addextendedproperty @name = 'dbUniqueIdentifier' @value = 'ABCD1234'
```

To confirm:

```
select value from sys.extended_properties where name = 'dbUniqueIdentifier'
```

In my organization, we use extended properties to identify which build and changeset the database schema came from. The properties survive backup/restore/migration.